# Angular2 detect OnChange

Tags: javascript, angular

i have code select option on angular2 like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="government">Provinsi</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="provinsi" formControlName="provinsi">
      <option *ngFor="let item of province" value="{{item.id}}" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">{{item.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="government">Kabupaten/Kota</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="kokab" formControlName="kokab">
      <option *ngFor="let list of regencieslist" value="{{list.id}}" selected="selected">{{list.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

What i want is. if i select the option of Provinsi select form it will trigger some method with value in it. how to trigger method on change with value pass to it

```
onChange(id){
      this.servicedev.getregencies(id).subscribe(
        regencies => this.regencieslist = regencies,
        error => error
      )
    }
```

i wanna trigger the onchange method and pass the value from provinsi select to the id onChange method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ngModelChange` works with `ngModel`, where you specify how you could handle the changing for the binding property. Looks like your issue is simple, you need the `change` event, from html select:

```
<select 
  class="form-control" 
  name="provinsi" 
  formControlName="provinsi" 
  (change)="onChange($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let item of province" value="{{item.id}}" >{{item.name}}</option>
</select>

onChange(event){
  if(event.target.value === /*something*/) {
    this.servicedev.getregencies(id).subscribe(
      regencies => this.regencieslist = regencies,
      error => error)
  }
}
```

Comment: oh yah. my bad sorry, it doesnt work with ng model. 
but i cant get the value pass to the onchange. how to resolve that

Comment: You could actually pass the value directly into the event handler: `(click)="onChange(item.id)"`, meaning no need to check the value on `element.target`.

Comment: @maddockst sure you can do it also, but is fancy to pass the event as default js :)